# subset function with "different than"?

Tags: r, dataframe

is it possible to use the subset function by saying sth like subset(dataset, IA_LABEL not equal to "Er" or "Sie" or "Es" or "wird" or  "gleich") ?
what interests me is the "not equal to" operator, is there something like that for the subset function?

thanks,
Katerina

Answer (score 18):

If you are wanting to exclude all of those words, then you are better of using a combination of the negation (NOT) operator, `!`, and set membership, `%in%`.

```
wordList <- c("Er","Sie","Es","wird","gleich")
subset(dataset, !(IA_LABEL %in% wordList))
```

To make it case insensitive you might want to wrap each of them in `toupper` or `tolower`.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it by a minute or so... The parenthesis makes it clearer, but isn't strictly required. `!` has lower precedence than `%in%`.

Answer (score 7):

The not equal operator is written `!=`

See `?Comparison` for details.

An example using `subset`:

```
> subset(airquality, Day != 1, select = -Temp)[1:5, ]
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Month Day
2    36     118  8.0     5   2
3    12     149 12.6     5   3
4    18     313 11.5     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9     5   6
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `%nin%` function in `Hmisc`

```
require(Hmisc)
subset(dataset, IA_LABEL %nin% wordList)
```